# misplaced table of contents' indentation with \addcontentsline and beamer

Tags: beamer

I am not able to fix the misplacd indentation, see below. Also, I should not use `\newline` within `\addcontentsline`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}

\usetheme{Antibes} 
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\useoutertheme{tree}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}


    \begin{frame} 
\tableofcontents 
    \end{frame} 


    \begin{frame} 
\section{section one}
    \end{frame} 

    \begin{frame} 
\subsection{subsection one}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{line added to TOC:  AAA \newline}
    \end{frame} 

    \begin{frame} 
\subsection{subsection two}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{line added to TOC: BBB \newline}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{line added to TOC: CCC \newline}
    \end{frame} 

    \begin{frame} 
\subsubsection{subsubsection after addcontentsline: three}
    LAST
    \end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Beamer does not support chapters

Comment: Beamer also does not do page numbers in toc. Try without the `\numberline` macro. It also does not like content outside of frames ...

Comment: Your question sounds a lot like a xy-question. Can you add what you are actually trying to do?

Comment: thanks to your comments, a fixed a couple of things, and update my question. Still it does not work perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using the square subsection template for the toc, you can look up how far it is indented (https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/blob/main/base/beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty#L268) and then indent your custom lines by the same amount:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Antibes} 
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\useoutertheme{tree}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame} 
\tableofcontents 
\end{frame} 

\section{section one}
\begin{frame} 

\end{frame} 

\subsection{subsection one}
\addtocontents{toc}{\hskip5ex line added to TOC:  AAA \par}
\begin{frame} 

\end{frame} 

\subsection{subsection two}
\addtocontents{toc}{\hskip5ex line added to TOC: BBB \par}
\addtocontents{toc}{\hskip5ex line added to TOC: CCC \par}
\begin{frame} 

\end{frame} 

\subsubsection{subsubsection after addcontentsline: three}
\begin{frame} 
LAST
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: how do I know that I am using the square subsection template?

Comment: @mario The blue square in front of the subsections gives this away :)

Comment: ... alternatively you could follow the lead through your themes. Your Antibes theme loads the `rectangles` inner theme and this inner theme then loads the square `subsection in toc` template and then you know which template is used.