# beamer, `pausesections` and `\addcontentsline`, how do I use them for the same table of contents?

Tags: beamer

In a beamer document,  I am trying to customize a table of contents with `pausesections` and  `\addcontentsline`, (see my previous questions [first](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/693983/beamer-tableofcontents-how-do-i-split-on-two-pages-a-very-long-list-of-subsec/694017#694017) and [second](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/694105/misplaced-table-of-contents-indentation-with-addcontentsline-and-beamer/694112?noredirect=1#comment1722713_694112)). You may see how the added toc items get repeated out of place. Your help is appreciated.

```
\documentclass{beamer}   
\usetheme{Antibes} 
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\useoutertheme{tree}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}
 
\begin{frame}[t]
    \frametitle{Index} 
    \tableofcontents[pausesections, pausesubsections,sections={-1}]
\end{frame} 
\begin{frame}[t,noframenumbering]
    \frametitle{Index} 
    \tableofcontents[pausesections, pausesubsections,sections={2-2}]
\end{frame} 
\begin{frame}[t,noframenumbering]
    \frametitle{Index} 
    \tableofcontents[pausesections, pausesubsections,sections={3-3}]
\end{frame} 
\begin{frame}[t,noframenumbering]
    \frametitle{Index} 
    \tableofcontents[pausesections, pausesubsections,sections={4-}]
\end{frame} 
 
 
        \begin{frame} 
    \section{section one \& A}
        \end{frame} 
        \begin{frame} 
    \subsection{subsection one}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\hskip5ex line added to TOC:  AAA \par}
            \end{frame} 
        \begin{frame} 
    \subsection{subsection two}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\hskip5ex line added to TOC: BBB \par}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\hskip5ex line added to TOC: CCC \par}
        \end{frame} 
 
        \begin{frame} 
    \subsubsection{subsubsection after addcontentsline: three}
        LAST
        \end{frame} 
    

    \section{B} B
    \subsection{1} B1
    \subsection{2} B2
    \subsection{3} B3
    \subsection{4} B4
    \section{C}
    \subsection{1} C1
    \subsection{2} C2
    \subsection{3} C3
    \subsection{4}
    \subsection{5}
    \subsection{6}
    \subsection{7}
    \subsection{8}
    \subsection{9}
    \subsection{10}
    \subsection{11}
    \subsection{12}
    \subsection{13}
    \subsection{14}
    \subsection{15}
    \subsection{16}
    \section{D}
    \subsection{1}
    \subsection{2}
    \subsection{3}
    \subsection{4}
    \section{E}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: failed output]

Comment: If you look at the aux file, beamer's toc has no resemblance to a normal toc whatsoever.  beamer: `\@writefile{toc}{\beamer@subsectionintoc {1}{1}{subsection one}{34}{0}{1}}` vs `\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\hskip 5ex line added to TOC: AAA}{34}{}\protected@file@percent }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/513634/36296 to show your additional text only on certain toc frames:

```
\documentclass{beamer}   
\usetheme{Antibes} 
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\useoutertheme{tree}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\let\testA\relax
\let\testB\relax

\begin{document}
 
\begin{frame}[t]
    \frametitle{Index} 
    \tableofcontents[pausesections, pausesubsections,sections={-1}]
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}[t,noframenumbering]
\let\testA\iffalse
\let\testB\fi
    \frametitle{Index} 
    \tableofcontents[pausesections, pausesubsections,sections={2-2}]
\end{frame} 
\begin{frame}[t,noframenumbering]
\let\testA\iffalse
\let\testB\fi
    \frametitle{Index} 
    \tableofcontents[pausesections, pausesubsections,sections={3-3}]
\end{frame} 
\begin{frame}[t,noframenumbering]
\let\testA\iffalse
\let\testB\fi
    \frametitle{Index} 
    \tableofcontents[pausesections, pausesubsections,sections={4-}]
\end{frame} 
 
 
    \section{section one \& A}
    \subsection{subsection one}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\testA\hskip5ex line added to TOC:  AAA \par\testB    }
    \subsection{subsection two}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\testA\hskip5ex line added to TOC: BBB \par\testB}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\testA\hskip5ex line added to TOC: CCC \par\testB}
    
 
    \subsubsection{subsubsection after addcontentsline: three} 
    \section{B} 
    \subsection{1} 
    \subsection{2} 
    \subsection{3} 
    \subsection{4} 
    \section{C}
    \subsection{1} 
    \subsection{2} 
    \subsection{3} 
    \subsection{4}
    \subsection{5}
    \subsection{6}
    \subsection{7}
    \subsection{8}
    \subsection{9}
    \subsection{10}
    \subsection{11}
    \subsection{12}
    \subsection{13}
    \subsection{14}
    \subsection{15}
    \subsection{16}
    \section{D}
    \subsection{1}
    \subsection{2}
    \subsection{3}
    \subsection{4}
    \section{E}
    \begin{frame}
    content...
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: clever, I need to do some homework to undertsand it, but it works.